# Binding List<DataTime> to DataGrid Header

Tags: wpf, list, datetime, data-binding, datagrid

Hi I have list of days in given month and I would like to bind this list to datagrid control.

Here is method which create a list of date.

```
public List<DateTime> DaysOfMonth { get; set; }

public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) 
                     .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)) 
                     .ToList(); 
}


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DaysOfMonth = GetDates(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
    DataContext = this;
}
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DaysOfMonth}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid>
```

I would like achieve this look

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you want to create columns from your list, you probably should create those in code behind iterating over the list, also i doubt that the CellTemplate is what you want to set, the [`HeaderTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.headertemplate.aspx) seems to be the target.

As columns normally reflect properties on an item in a DataGrid this might not be such a good idea, what do your rows represent?